# My BlueJ source code got deleted

Tags: java, project, bluej

I was doing my school project today when suddenly my java BlueJ crashed and both my current file and my backup file got deleted.

One of my most important classes(SignIn.java) got deleted(only the source code).

While executing, it still works as it is linked but i can't find the source code to make changes or print it. There is a file with #BACKUP which might help me.

Is there anyway i can retrieve it? I spent almost 6 hours on this class and it took a lot of work.

Comment: I am not familiar with BlueJ but there should be an output-folder which contains the compiled java file. You could decompile it

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in their [manual](http://www.bluej.org/doc/bluej-ref-manual.pdf) at page 42 the `#backup` file is always saved in the same directory so your `#backup` file should be gone.

If you versioned it with svn or alike in the `Team` menu you can get `Project History`.

Otherwise.... you can use some [file recovery programs](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm).

The most popular can search for source codes in many languages.
The advantage of this approach is that you will recover comments meanwhile you won't by decompiling.

Answer (score 1):

If your source code is truly gone (non-recoverable) you can try to use a de-compiler against the .class file.  Jad and FernFlower are two that I've used and work pretty well.

https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower

http://www.javadecompilers.com/jad

Answer (score -1):

to find a file you need the program's interface to open the folderis was deleted from or go to the folder content aware analysis and select the file you have been looking for and click rec

Comment: This is AI generated answer.